# C# application getting Access is denied. HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)

Tags: c#, iis, wmi, impersonation, access-denied

I have the following on my c# code:

```
ConnectionOptions connOptions = new ConnectionOptions();
connOptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
//connOptions.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy;
connOptions.EnablePrivileges = true;
ManagementScope manScope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + remoteMachine + "\\ROOT\\CIMV2"), connOptions);
manScope.Connect();
```

I also granted my Application Pool Identity access to the application (read, write) and followed the instructions provided by Microsoft at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394603%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> Possible Issues: The user does not have remote access to the computer through DCOM. Typically, DCOM errors occur when connecting to a remote computer with a different operating system version.
>
> Solution: Give the user Remote Launch and Remote Activation permissions in dcomcnfg. Right-click My Computer-> Properties Under COM Security, click "Edit Limits" for both sections. Give the user you want remote access, remote launch, and remote activation. Then go to DCOM Config, find "Windows Management Instrumentation", and give the user you want Remote Launch and Remote Activation. For more information, see Connecting Between Different Operating Systems

When running my application I still get the Access denied error message tough.

```
Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
Stack Trace: [UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))]
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo) +0
System.Management.ManagementScope.InitializeGuts(Object o) +657
System.Management.ManagementScope.Initialize() +359
Tool.WebForm1.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +3647
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3178
```

Any ideas what else I should do/change? Thanks.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/26accc30-9cfb-4d86-9c27-780f51929ecb/access-is-denied-exception-from-hresult-0x80070005-eaccessdenied?forum=vsreportcontrols may be this link could be of some help/

Comment: that was done too but it didn't help. same thing.